# why can't python use global and local scope for same variable in a function

Tags: python, scopes

While learning python, I have an understanding that python runs Line by line and unless a line of code is not executed it does not create or assign variable and all was fine with this theory, until I tried something like:

```
X = 1

def method1():
    print (X)  # Why global X, is not printed here
    X = 20
    print (X)  # and then use local X here
```

I know global keyword can solve it also if I remove the assignment of X inside method1() would solve it and global X gets printed, but I am not able to understand how python knows before hand that I have a var assignment of same name somewhere down the code in function?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: The answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function#423596

Comment: Python scans your code before running it, as showing in the example below. That's why if you make an indentation error, it knows (e.g., having an `if` statement with no body).

Answer (score 1):

The scope cannot be mixed within a code block.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names

(emphasis mine)

> **If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all
>   uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the
>   current block**. This can lead to errors when a name is used within a
>   block before it is bound. This rule is subtle. Python lacks
>   declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere
>   within a code block. The local variables of a code block can be
>   determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name binding
>   operations.